# Issuing a rollback() in an atomic block

Tags: django

I'm attempting to update my code that uses `commit_manually` to `atomic` to go to Django 1.7 then 1.8 but I'm having issues not being able to `rollback` while in an atomic block. The issue stems from a flag we added to out import routines, dry_run. In the prior Django versions `@commit_manually` allowed us to do the following:

```
 if self.dry_run:
    transaction.rollback()
 else:
    transaction.commit()
```

If I attempt to preform a roll back in an `atomic` block it throws an error:

> TransactionManagementError : "This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active."

To get this to work I tried to make use of `set_autocommit`

**Example:**

```
def do_some_import(self)
  transaction.set_autocommit(False)

  #import routine

  if self.dry_run:
            transaction.rollback()
            transaction.set_autocommit(True)
        else:
            transaction.commit()
            transaction.set_autocommit(True)
```

But this feels wrong any suggestions or insights?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [`set_rollback()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.set_rollback)? I think that will solve your problem.

```
@transaction.atomic
def do_some_import(self):
    #import routine

    if self.dry_run:
        transaction.set_rollback(True)
```

Comment: I completely read over that section of the docs I'll test and get back to you thanks!